# create a column of boxes at the center of a background rectangle

Tags: html, css

I want to create a row of boxes aligned in the center of a background rectangle like this:

[image]

Note that we may have **more than two boxes** or just a single one.

creating a column of boxes shouldn't be a complicated task but, the issue is when you want those paddings above and below the background rectangle things (at least for me) goes complicated.

I can calculate al this using javascript but I wonder if there is a solution using pure CSS.

[Here is the Codepen](https://codepen.io/pixy-dixy/pen/dyMGBWe) and the code:

```css
body {
  background-color: #FDFDFD;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.subbox-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 0.195vw;
  min-width: 0;
}

.main-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 98vh;
  gap: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  min-width: 0; 
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px dashed;
}

.background-rectangle {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin-right: 0 !important;
  min-width: 0; 
}

.box-container {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  min-width: 0;
}

* { min-width: 0; }

.box, .background-rectangle {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.background-rectangle {
  background-color: #E6E0EC;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.box{
  background-color: coral;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">

    <!-- box-container start -->

    <div id="box-container-1" class="box-container">

    <div class="subbox-container">

        <!-- Start Box -->
        <div class ="box" style="min-width: 0; margin: 0; z-index: 4; width: 15.54vw; height: 5.59vh; opacity: 1;">
        </div>
        <!-- End Box -->


        <!-- Start Box -->
        <div class ="box" style="min-width: 0; margin: 0; z-index: 4; width: 15.54vw; height: 5.59vh; opacity: 1;" aria-label="do you ever">
        </div>
        <!-- End Box -->

    </div>

    <!-- background rectangle -->
    <div class="background-rectangle" style="min-width: 0; height: 16.81vh; width: 15.54vw;">
    </div>

    <!-- box-container end -->

</div> <!-- main container end-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remove from your html and add class background-rectangle  to subbox-container

```
<div class="background-rectangle" style="min-width: 0; height: 16.81vh; width: 15.54vw;">
</div>
```

if you add opacity to background color then convert into rgb the add last value as opacity #E6E0EC(rgb(230,224,236)) and 0.7 in rgb value
`background-color: #E6E0EC` to `background-color:rgb(230,224,236,0.7);`

And add this style to `subbox-container`

```
  min-width: 0;
  height: 16.81vh;
  width: 15.54vw;
  padding: 20px 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #FDFDFD;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.subbox-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 0.195vw;
  min-width: 0;
  min-width: 0;
  height: 16.81vh;
  width: 15.54vw;
  padding: 20px 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.main-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 98vh;
  gap: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  min-width: 0; 
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px dashed;
}

.background-rectangle {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin-right: 0 !important;
  min-width: 0;
}

.box-container {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  min-width: 0;
}

* { min-width: 0; }

.box, .background-rectangle {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.background-rectangle {
  background-color: rgb(230,224,236,0.7);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.box{
  background-color: coral;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">

    <!-- box-container start -->

    <div id="box-container-1" class="box-container">

    <div class="subbox-container background-rectangle">

        <!-- Start Box -->
        <div class ="box" style="min-width: 0; margin: 0; z-index: 4; width: 15.54vw; height: 5.59vh; opacity: 1;">
        </div>
        <!-- End Box -->


        <!-- Start Box -->
        <div class ="box" style="min-width: 0; margin: 0; z-index: 4; width: 15.54vw; height: 5.59vh; opacity: 1;" aria-label="do you ever">
        </div>
        <!-- End Box -->

    </div>


    <!-- box-container end -->

</div> <!-- main container end-->
```

More about flexbox : [Aligning Items in a Flex Container](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container)

Comment: I need an opacity: 0.07; for the background rectangle!

Comment: ok @Pixier 
if you add opacity to ```background-color``` then convert into ```rgb``` the add last value . ```#E6E0EC``` in rgb value ```rgb(230,224,236)``` add opacity ```0.7``` in rgb value to convert hex to rgb : https://www.rgbtohex.net/hextorgb/
```background-color: #E6E0EC``` to ```background-color:rgb(230,224,236,0.7);```

Answer (score 0):

I think i may have understood correctly that this is your end goal:

https://codepen.io/liam88/pen/RwarzvO

I have simplified the elements needed.

Overall, your surrounding box container could just use a simple padding top/bottom to give the needed space without having to calc anything.

The elements in the surround will always center as we are using flexbox with the justify and align properties.

If I missed the goal, let me know.

```
    <div class="main-container">

    <!-- box-container start -->
  <div class="flex surround">
    <!-- each box under -->
    <div class="flex-item box">
    </div>
    <div class="flex-item box">
    </div>
  </div>
</div> <!-- main container end-->

body {
  background-color: #FDFDFD;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.main-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 98vh;
  gap: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  min-width: 0; 
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px dashed;
  background:lightblue;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 0.195vw;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
}
.surround{
  width:50%; /* width set to view easily */
  background:lightgrey;
  border-radius:10px;
  padding:20px 0;
}
.box{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  min-height:50px;
  background:coral;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer.. plus one ... I'll test this in my code and come back to you...

Comment: I need an `opacity: 0.07;` for the background rectangle!

Comment: @Pixier I have adjusted the codepen to include a background that uses RGBA. That allows you to use the last rule to adjust the opacity. It's currently 0.7. Closer to 0, the more transparent, closer to 1, the less transparency.

Answer (score 0):

hi i've made some update on your code, i've commented the old html and css.

here you can find a semplified version with less css:

[codepen version](https://codepen.io/eroinbob84/pen/GRZoVpR)

```css
body {
  background-color: #FDFDFD;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.subbox-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 0.195vw;
  min-width: 0;
}

.main-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 98vh;
  gap: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  min-width: 0; 
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px dashed;
}

.background-rectangle {
  /*left: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin-right: 0 !important;
  min-width: 0;*/ 
}

.box-container {
  /*position: relative;
  top: 0;
  min-width: 0;*/
}

* { min-width: 0; }

.box, .background-rectangle {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.background-rectangle {
  background-color: #E6E0EC;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 20px 2px;
}

.box{
  background-color: coral;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">

    <!-- box-container start -->

    <div id="box-container-1" class="box-container">

    <div class="subbox-container background-rectangle">

        <!-- Start Box -->
        <div class ="box" style="min-width: 0; margin: 0; z-index: 4; width: 15.54vw; height: 5.59vh; opacity: 1;">
        </div>
        <!-- End Box -->


        <!-- Start Box -->
        <div class ="box" style="min-width: 0; margin: 0; z-index: 4; width: 15.54vw; height: 5.59vh; opacity: 1;" aria-label="do you ever">
        </div>
        <!-- End Box -->

    </div>

    <!-- background rectangle 
    <div class="background-rectangle" style="min-width: 0; height: 16.81vh; width: 15.54vw;">
    </div>-->

    <!-- box-container end -->

</div> <!-- main container end-->
```

Comment: I need an opacity: 0.07; for the background rectangle only!